# How to add a key/value to a dict in an ansible playbook, conditional

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Let's say I want to add `InterestingVar` dict key and the associated value when the variable `test_var` exists (passed with `-e in command line`), how can I do that ?

```
# ansible-playbook ./add_to_dict_on_condition.yml -i 127.0.0.1, -e env=test -e test_var=123
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - tags:
        InterestingVar: "{{test_var}}" # How to omit this line if test_var == '' ?
        Name: xxx
        Env: "{{ env }}"

  tasks:
    - debug: var=tags
```

I tested

```
 InterestingVar: "{{test_var|default(omit)}}
```

but I get :

```
"InterestingVar": "__omit_place_holder__caca01e207397883640613b08e8ce3a8fbdd6"
```

instead of nothing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I use `ansible 1.8`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to combine dictionaries with a [`set_fact`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) task when your condition is met. This relies on the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) introduced in Ansible 2.0.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - tags:
        Name: xxx
        Env: "{{ env }}"
    - optional_tags:
        InterestingVar: "{{ test_var }}"

  tasks:
    - name: combine tags
      set_fact:
        tags: "{{ tags | combine(optional_tags) }}"
      when: test_var is defined

    - name: debug tags
      debug: var=tags
```

Which outputs the following then test_var is not defined:

```
vagrant@Test-02:~$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," conditional_key.yml -e "env=test"

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [combine tags] ************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug tags] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "tags": {
        "Env": "test",
        "Name": "xxx"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And this output when it is defined:

```
vagrant@Test-02:~$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," conditional_key.yml -e "env=test" -e "test_var=123"

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [combine tags] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug tags] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "tags": {
        "Env": "test",
        "InterestingVar": "123",
        "Name": "xxx"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If you are unable to use 2.0+ then another option may be to change [Ansible's hash behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) to merge dictionaries rather than overriding them by setting:

```
hash_behaviour=merge
```

in your `ansible.cfg`.

With this you could then use something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - tags:
        Name: xxx
        Env: "{{ env }}"
    - tags:
        InterestingVar: "{{ test_var }}"

  tasks:
    - name: debug tags
      debug: var=tags
```

With your vars defined in the following files:

```
vagrant@Test-01:~$ cat tags.yml
tags:
  Name: xxx
  Env: "{{ env }}"
vagrant@Test-01:~$ cat optional_tags.yml
tags:
  InterestingVar: "{{ test_var }}"
```

This then gives you the output you want but you have to make sure not to include `optional_vars.yml` when you don't have `test_var` defined:

```
vagrant@Test-01:~$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," conditional_key.yml -e "env=test" -e "test_var=123" -e@tags.yml -e@optional_tags.yml

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK: [debug tags] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "tags": {
            "Env": "test",
            "InterestingVar": "123",
            "Name": "xxx"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Be aware that when using this approach any expected overriding of dictionaries through inheritance will now merge the dictionaries instead so this may not be all that useful for anyone overriding things in their inventories.

Comment: Any chance to have a workaround to use this logic in ansible 1.8 ?

Comment: I've edited my post to give a slightly cleaner approach but this is still 2.0+ unfortunately. There is the option to get Ansible to merge dicts rather than replace them without the `combine` filter but this may have bad effects elsewhere if you are expecting inheritance to override things. I'll add it to my answer though.

Comment: I've added a pre 2.0 workaround but it's not a pretty one unfortunately and may have worse side effects (as mentioned in my above comment). If you really want this functionality then I'd consider upgrading to 2.0.